# Creating a dataframe from another one by column values

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe (df1)

```
> df1
  var1 var2 var3 df2
1   ac   bc   bc  0
2   bc   bc   cc  1
3   dc   ec   dc  1
4   gc   gc   gc  0
```

I would like to get a new dataframe (df2) that will contain only the values of 1 in column df2. 
df2 will be as followed:

```
> df2
      var1 var2 var3  
    2   bc   bc   cc  
    3   dc   ec   dc
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `df1[df1$df2 == 1, -4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subset should work:

```
df2 <- subset(df1, df2 !=0)
df2 <- df2[,1:3]
df2
#var1 var2 var3
#2   bc   bc   cc
#3   dc   ec   dc
```